# Replacing a static mount with AutoFS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fstab, autofs, automount

My /etc/fstab looks something like this:

```
files:/var/files/emails /var/www/emails nfs rw 0 0
files:/var/files/images /var/www/images nfs rw 0 0
```

My /etc/auto.master looks like this:

```
/net   /etc/auto.net
```

I am kinda lost after this. What do I need to next to get these mount point? Also there are lots of sub-directories under each mount point, I had read somewhere that there are problems with sub-directories, is this still the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have enabled auto.net which is a executable mount map then it will automatically create the maps for you.

You would need to restart autofs after making those changes if you haven't.  Then simply **cd** into the directory /net/servername/path/to/files.  When you access the directory the network resource will be mounted.

Check your /var/log/syslog for errors if you weren't able to access the directory.

Comment: It will create the mounts by looking at /etc/fstab or do I have to specify the paths somewhere else?

Comment: Nevermind on the last question, I think I understand. I am just using a 10.10.X.X to connect to the file server, how do I figure out the server name?

Comment: The servername would be whatever name or identifier you use to access the system.  I believe you can also use an IP address.  If not, you could simply make up whatever name you want and put it in your /etc/hosts file.